# Using react-facebook-login with React version 18

Tags: reactjs

I am looking to use react-facebook-login library with React version 18 but I am unable to install the package.

npm is throwing error on the console ?
Does the the library support version 18 of React?
Any work around and alternate method?

Many thanks....

Comment: Please share the error message.

Comment: @AlexV
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: btk@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-facebook-login@4.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-facebook-login
npm ERR!   react-facebook-login@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 0):

Because `react-facebook-login@latest` necessitates `react@^16.0.0` as its peer dependency, and you currently have `react@18` installed in your project, this warning has been triggered.

**Option 1:**
To resolve this issue, consider downgrading your React version from `18` to `^16.0.0`, and then proceed to reinstall `react-facebook-login`.

**Option 2:**
Alternatively, you can force the installation of `react-facebook-login` using either of the following commands:

```
npm install react-facebook-login -S --force

npm install react-facebook-login -S --legacy-peer-deps
```

**Option 3:**
Another approach is to use `npm i @greatsumini/react-facebook-login` instead of the standard `npm i react-facebook-login`. This package may offer compatibility with your current React version.